# Accessing elements inside parenthesis in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

So i have this predicate `letras_comuns(Lst_Pals, Letras_comuns)` in which `Lst_Pals` is a list of like `[[a,t,o],[a,c,o],[a,n,o]]` and `Letras_comuns` is the a list with all the elements common in every word at a given index, e.g. `[(1,a), (3,o)]`.

Example:

```
?- Lst_Pals = [[a,t,o], [a,c,o], [a,n,o], [a,l,o]],
      letras_comuns(Lst_Pals, Letras_comuns).
   Lst_Pals = [[a, t, o], [a, c, o], [a, n, o], [a, l, o]],
   Letras_comuns = [(a, 1),  (o, 3)].
```

So basically what this means is that all the words in `Lst_pals` have an `a` in the 1st index and an `o` in the  3rd/last index.

The problem is that i want to access to the elements inside the parenthesis and i know if put `(X,Y) = (a,1)` i can access its elements, the thing is that this only works for `1` and i want to access to all of them, so anyone can tell me how because i'm clueless on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define

```
p( (X,Y), X, Y ).
```

then use it:

```
?- p( (a,1), A, I ).

A = a,
I = 1.
```

or

```
?- maplist( p, [(a, 1),  (o, 3)], AS, IS).

AS = [a, o],
IS = [1, 3].
```